Using AppleScript to start a Quicktime movie recording AFTER the recording window has been opened
I'm trying to write separate AppleScripts where one opens a new movie recording in Quicktime Player, and then a second script begins the actual recording. Currently I have a script that opens the new movie recording, a script that opens the new movie recording and begins recording immediately, but when I try to start the recording after the new recording window has opened, I just get error messages.
I'm new to AppleScript, so I'm very naive on terms and best practices.
